# Mup deploy failed at verification, 172.17.0.4 port 80: Connection Refused

Tags: javascript, docker, meteor, digital-ocean, mup

`mup.deploy` failed at `verifying deployment`.

```
C:\...appPath...>mup.cmd deploy --verbose
Building App Bundle Locally

Started TaskList: Pushing Meteor App
[188.166.224.###] - Pushing Meteor App Bundle to the Server
[188.166.224.###] - Pushing Meteor App Bundle to the Server: SUCCESS
[188.166.224.###] - Prepare Bundle
node-8.4.0-base: Pulling from abernix/meteord
Digest: sha256:04f44cf999da383d11de77027ced8b70818222c9890a405ce10803af3ee5a642
Status: Image is up to date for abernix/meteord:node-8.4.0-base
Finished Extracting
Creating Dockerfile
Finished creating Dockerfile
Building image
Sending build context to Docker daemon  204.3MB
Step 1/7 : FROM abernix/meteord:node-8.4.0-base
# Executing 1 build trigger
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6458e2a72353
Step 2/7 : RUN mkdir /built_app || true
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 320822163072
Step 3/7 : ENV PORT=8080
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7af3c2ab0d1f
Step 4/7 : ENV ROOT_URL=http://erp.infil.com.my
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f6e3276c21a5
Step 5/7 : ENV MONGO_URL=mongodb://mongodb:27017/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 71167fd893d0
Step 6/7 : COPY ./ /built_app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 82b608fb889d
Step 7/7 : RUN cd  /built_app/programs/server &&     npm install --unsafe-perm
 ---> Using cache
 ---> caeffcadcdd4
Successfully built caeffcadcdd4
Successfully tagged mup-app:build
Total reclaimed space: 0B
[188.166.224.###] - Prepare Bundle: SUCCESS

Started TaskList: Configuring App
[188.166.224.###] - Pushing the Startup Script
[188.166.224.###] - Pushing the Startup Script: SUCCESS
[188.166.224.###] - Sending Environment Variables
[188.166.224.###] - Sending Environment Variables: SUCCESS

Started TaskList: Start Meteor
[188.166.224.###] - Start Meteor
using image
removing last
Image mup-app:latest
Volume
Removing docker containers. Errors about nonexistent endpoints and containers are normal.
app
Error response from daemon: endpoint app not found
Error: No such container: app-frontend
Error response from daemon: endpoint app-frontend not found
Error: No such container: app-nginx-letsencrypt
Error response from daemon: endpoint app-nginx-letsencrypt not found
Error: No such container: app-nginx-proxy
Error response from daemon: endpoint app-nginx-proxy not found
Finished removing docker containers
5470f594f3e2997b7313db90ed45536952212087c0656a4cd4de3a5bae9c2312
Ran abernix/meteord:node-8.4.0-base
[188.166.224.###] - Start Meteor: SUCCESS
[188.166.224.###] - Verifying Deployment
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.3 port 80: Connection refused
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.3 port 80: Connection refused
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.3 port 80: Connection refused
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.3 port 80: Connection refused
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.3 port 80: Connection refused
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.3 port 80: Connection refused
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.3 port 80: Connection refused
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.3 port 80: Connection refused
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.3 port 80: Connection refused
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.3 port 80: Connection refused
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.3 port 80: Connection refused
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.3 port 80: Connection refused
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.3 port 80: Connection refused
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.3 port 80: Connection refused
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.3 port 80: Connection refused
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.3 port 80: Connection refused
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.3 port 80: Connection refused
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.3 port 80: Connection refused
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.3 port 80: Connection refused
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.3 port 80: Connection refused
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.3 port 80: Connection refused
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.3 port 80: Connection refused
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.3 port 80: Connection refused
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.3 port 80: Connection refused
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.3 port 80: Connection refused
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.3 port 80: Connection refused
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.3 port 80: Connection refused
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.3 port 80: Connection refused
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.3 port 80: Connection refused
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.3 port 80: Connection refused
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.3 port 80: Connection refused
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.3 port 80: Connection refused
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.3 port 80: Connection refused
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.3 port 80: Connection refused
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.3 port 80: Connection refused
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.3 port 80: Connection refused
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.3 port 80: Connection refused
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.3 port 80: Connection refused
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.3 port 80: Connection refused
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.3 port 80: Connection refused
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.3 port 80: Connection refused
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.3 port 80: Connection refused
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.3 port 80: Connection refused
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.3 port 80: Connection refused
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.3 port 80: Connection refused
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.3 port 80: Connection refused
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.3 port 80: Connection refused

=> Container status:
restarted: 0 times {"Bridge":"","SandboxID":"3475f3031854cb5c2cbd1d673399ffb295c6a1913e268820550fca4dc786becf","HairpinMode":false,"LinkLocalIPv6Address":"","LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen":0,"Ports":{"80/tcp":[{"HostIp":"0.0.0.0","HostPort":"8080"}]},"SandboxKey":"/var/run/docker/netns/3475f3031854","SecondaryIPAddresses":null,"SecondaryIPv6Addresses":null,"EndpointID":"1f739b58a0a26c8e599bdd6c6ae690f8d6c6629ed95fafecac1ccf863dc2406a","Gateway":"172.17.0.1","GlobalIPv6Address":"","GlobalIPv6PrefixLen":0,"IPAddress":"172.17.0.3","IPPrefixLen":16,"IPv6Gateway":"","MacAddress":"02:42:ac:11:00:03","Networks":{"bridge":{"IPAMConfig":null,"Links":null,"Aliases":null,"NetworkID":"931361bae67f395afc03e55a3fbf98dee8179feb1d38b9a194dd03614482ccfa","EndpointID":"1f739b58a0a26c8e599bdd6c6ae690f8d6c6629ed95fafecac1ccf863dc2406a","Gateway":"172.17.0.1","IPAddress":"172.17.0.3","IPPrefixLen":16,"IPv6Gateway":"","GlobalIPv6Address":"","GlobalIPv6PrefixLen":0,"MacAddress":"02:42:ac:11:00:03","DriverOpts":null}}} {"Status":"running","Running":true,"Paused":false,"Restarting":false,"OOMKilled":false,"Dead":false,"Pid":21572,"ExitCode":0,"Error":"","StartedAt":"2019-08-27T16:10:30.738119744Z","FinishedAt":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"}
=> Logs:
=> Starting meteor app on port:80
superadmin exists
Config file not found
Monti APM: Successfully connected

=> Redeploying previous version of the app


To see more logs type 'mup logs --tail=200'

[188.166.224.###] x Verifying Deployment: FAILED

              ------------------------------------STDERR------------------------------------
               to connect to 172.17.0.3 port 80: Connection refused
          % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                         Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.3 port 80: Connection refused
          % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                         Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.3 port 80: Connection refused
          % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                         Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.3 port 80: Connection refused
          % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                         Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.3 port 80: Connection refused
          % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                         Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.3 port 80: Connection refused
          % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                         Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.3 port 80: Connection refused
          % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                         Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.3 port 80: Connection refused
          % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                         Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.3 port 80: Connection refused
          % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                         Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.3 port 80: Connection refused
          % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                         Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.3 port 80: Connection refused
          % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                         Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.3 port 80: Connection refused
          % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                         Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.3 port 80: Connection refused
          % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                         Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.3 port 80: Connection refused
        => Starting meteor app on port:80
        superadmin exists
        Config file not found
        Monti APM: Successfully connected

        => Redeploying previous version of the app


              ------------------------------------STDOUT------------------------------------
              => Container status:
        restarted: 0 times {"Bridge":"","SandboxID":"3475f3031854cb5c2cbd1d673399ffb295c6a1913e268820550fca4dc786becf","HairpinMode":false,"LinkLocalIPv6Address":"","LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen":0,"Ports":{"80/tcp":[{"HostIp":"0.0.0.0","HostPort":"8080"}]},"SandboxKey":"/var/run/docker/netns/3475f3031854","SecondaryIPAddresses":null,"SecondaryIPv6Addresses":null,"EndpointID":"1f739b58a0a26c8e599bdd6c6ae690f8d6c6629ed95fafecac1ccf863dc2406a","Gateway":"172.17.0.1","GlobalIPv6Address":"","GlobalIPv6PrefixLen":0,"IPAddress":"172.17.0.3","IPPrefixLen":16,"IPv6Gateway":"","MacAddress":"02:42:ac:11:00:03","Networks":{"bridge":{"IPAMConfig":null,"Links":null,"Aliases":null,"NetworkID":"931361bae67f395afc03e55a3fbf98dee8179feb1d38b9a194dd03614482ccfa","EndpointID":"1f739b58a0a26c8e599bdd6c6ae690f8d6c6629ed95fafecac1ccf863dc2406a","Gateway":"172.17.0.1","IPAddress":"172.17.0.3","IPPrefixLen":16,"IPv6Gateway":"","GlobalIPv6Address":"","GlobalIPv6PrefixLen":0,"MacAddress":"02:42:ac:11:00:03","DriverOpts":null}}} {"Status":"running","Running":true,"Paused":false,"Restarting":false,"OOMKilled":false,"Dead":false,"Pid":21572,"ExitCode":0,"Error":"","StartedAt":"2019-08-27T16:10:30.738119744Z","FinishedAt":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"}
        => Logs:

        To see more logs type 'mup logs --tail=200'


              ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I am running Windows10, after an update meteor could no longer start, running `meteor` runs into `cannot find module 'fibers'` error. Took me quite some time to fix, I think I ran `meteor update --release 1.6.1.2-rc.0` to fix it, however that is not the issue here.

I upgraded the droplet several times, and each time I upgrade I had to shutdown the droplet, so I `ssh` into the droplet, and ran `sudo shutdown -h now`.

After upgrading, the app works, and I can access it fine, now I have done some updates, but no longer able to deploy.

`mup.cmd setup` returns checks out, `mup.cmd reconfig` fails at verification.

I rebooted the droplet `sudo reboot` to attempt another deployment, but I noticed that each time I reboot the droplet, the IP Address in docker changed from `172.17.0.3` to `172.17.0.4` to `172.17.0.5`.

So far the deployment still fails at verification, with the same error messages but IP Address is different. I suspect there is an easy fix, but no matter how I dig I can't find any clues.

Is there any way I can reconfigure this IP Address or should I re-deploy another droplet just to save time?

Comment: Perhaps a silly question, but is port 80 open on your droplet?

Comment: Yes, Port 80 is definitely open, I eventually rebuilt another server and migrated across. There was no way I could solve this issue.

Comment: At least you solved it. Sometimes starting again is necessary :)

Comment: Probably best delete this question as it doesn't have a solution - there is no value in leaving it here.

Comment: I suppose this may be a bug with docker or mup, why would docker keep changing the ip address each time I restart the server, and mup perhaps should reference the docker id instead of the ip address... I'll leave it here a bit longer, eventually I'll delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to resolve this issue through luck...

After rebuilding another server and migrating across, I ran into this issue again. So I thought may be there was something in Windows 10 that is causing this issue. So I thought I would use WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) to resolve this.

After I managed to get meteor running on WSL, I noticed that I have not upgraded `mup` and `mup reconfig` ran successfully, after downgrading from `mup 1.4.6` to `mup 1.3.6`, everything worked, and I was able to deploy to my staging server again.